# verbatim with black background and white text

Tags: verbatim

How could I set up a verbatim-environment which has

- black background
- white text in scriptsize ?

Comment: use the listings package.

Comment: I did, but there it gives me small white lines between each textline. And on the other hand, there seems to be no other way to have completely white text within listings than \color{white}\begin{listing}...\end{listing}\color{black}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution inspired by the code of the `moreverb` package and using code lines of it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\makeatletter
\def\inverseverbatim{%
  \color{white}\scriptsize
  \def\verbatim@processline{%
    {\setbox0=\hbox{\the\verbatim@line}%
    \hsize=\wd0 \the\verbatim@line\par}}%
  \@minipagetrue
  \@tempswatrue
  \@totalleftmargin\z@
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup \verbatim
}
\def\endinverseverbatim{%
  \endverbatim
  \unskip\setbox0=\lastbox
  \egroup
  \colorbox{black}{\box0}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Test:

\begin{inverseverbatim}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
\end{inverseverbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]