# White-colored text and black background using the article class

Tags: backgrounds, text-decorations, article

I'm using the `article` class to generate an exam paper. In this exam paper, I want the subject header to be bold and centered aligned as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I tried a couple of options as mentioned in other posts, e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9033/verbatim-with-black-background-and-white-text).

Is there any way to get the same text effect with the `article` class without use of any extra package (like `verbatim`)?

Comment: `titlesec` should make this straight forward... without a package it's not quite so, but still doable

Comment: Please add a MWE. By subject header, do you mean the `\title` or `section`? You need at least `color` or `xcolor` packages.

Comment: Excuse be, but could you please give some justification for the "without use of extra package"? Why exactly do you dismiss existing solutions in existing packages? I mean, the whole point of LaTeX packages is modularity and composability for reuse and separation of concerns. So why instead you want reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without packages? uh. You need at least `xcolor`. Is it the section or the title? You don't want to use `tikz`? And no `titlesec` or `sectsty`? It is a pretty bad demand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\title{\sffamily\colorbox{black}{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{PART - III: MATHEMATICS}}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{\sffamily\colorbox{black}{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{PART - III: MATHEMATICS}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

No rounded corners as there is no `tikz` ;-)